# What does it mean to discard a hypotesis in a natural deduction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, axioms, natural-deduction

My textbook says that in the deductive system of natural deduction every hypotesis must be discarded by a rule of inference and after being discarded, it cannot be used again in the deduction... But then it presented me to this derivation for $A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow (A \land B))$:

$[A]^1$    $[B]^2$

________________$(\land I)^2$

$A \land B$

________________$(\rightarrow I)\times2$

$A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow (A \land B))$

By $"(\rightarrow I)\times2"$, I'm assuming he firstly did $(\rightarrow I)^2$ and then $(\rightarrow I)^1$.

But that confused me. Shouldn't $B$ be discarded after $(\land I)^2$? Does only the implication insertion rule discard hypothesis?

Comment: When you prove a theorem $T$ *under the hypotheses* $H$, what you have proved is that "T holds, provided that H is true". To discard the hypotheses or assumption is to move from above result to the new theorem "if H then T".

Comment: Wrt to the example above, YES, the assumptions (in square brackets) are discharged by the two *applications* of $\to$-Intro rule (see the $\times 2$ notation). Thus, you have something like: $((\to \text I) \times 2) ^{[2][1]}$

Comment: See also the post [What does discharging an assumption mean in Natural Deduction?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3527285/what-does-discharging-an-assumption-mean-in-natural-deduction)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thanks, but why wasn't  the assumption B discarded before after the application of $(\land I)^2$?

Comment: Maybe we have to review the notation used by your textbook... But the issue is that $(\land \text I)$ does not discharge assumptions. Thus, the sequence must be: $(A \land B)$ by $(\land \text I)$ followed by $B \to (A \land B)$ by $(\to \text I)$ discharging [2], followed by $A \to (B \to (A \land B))$ by $(\to \text I)$ discharging [1].

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake. It doesnt use $(\land I)^2$ but $(\land I)$. Does only the implication introduction discharge assumptions?

Comment: @Jonas Yes, only some rules discharge assumptions. And typically, it is treated such that you are *allowed* to discharge the assumptions, but don't have to if you want to leave them open for some reason.

Comment: No; see [Natural Deduction rules](https://iep.utm.edu/natural-deduction/#H4): also $(\lnot \text I), (\lor \text E)$ and in Classical Logic also $(\text {RAA})$.