Substitution principle for hypothetical judgements
I'm looking at this note (page 3) and I don't really understand the substitution principle stated there. Specifically,

What are "assumptions that are not discharged in the subproof"? In the example of implication on the same page, it is stated that $u$ is not discharged in $\mathcal E$. What does it mean and how to see that?

(Probably related) Why does the hypothetical proof of $B \ true$ in the statement of the substitution principle have a horizontal line with a label $u$ on top, i.e.,
$$\rule{3cm}{0.4pt}\textit{u}\\ 
A \ true  \\ 
\mathcal E \\
B \ true 
$$ as opposed to just having the form $$A \ true \\ 
\mathcal E \\ B \ true$$ ? The horizontal line with label $u$ is introduced in this note and my understanding was that the horizontal line with label $u$ introduces a "local subproof" (e.g. if we want to prove that $A\to B \ true$, then we need to "locally" assume $A$ and deduce $B$ from the local assumption $A$ and previous "more global" assumptions, if any). I think of it as an extra vertical line in Fitch-style deduction system. Why does the substitution principle is only stated for this kind of "local" assumption -- does it not work for global deduction trees (the ones without a horizontal line with label $u$) such as the one displayed above?

I'm not sure if I understand what "substituting $\mathcal D$ for all uses of the hypothesis labelled $u$ in $\mathcal E$" means. As far as I understand, $\mathcal D$ is itself a proof tree. What is "hypothesis labelled $u$? The thing labeled $u$ is this derivation tree $$\rule{3cm}{0.4pt}\textit{u}\\ 
A \ true  \\ 
\mathcal E \\
B \ true 
$$
and this tree has the empty hypothesis, as far as I can tell.



For the first question, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3527285/what-does-discharging-an-assumption-mean-in-natural-deduction

You are misreading the tree: the thing labelled $u$ is the inference of $A$ from no hypotheses; in other words, it's the hypothesis of $A$. Then $\mathcal{E}$ derives $B$ from $A$. You can see the whole proof tree as the application of $\mathcal{E}$ to a variable $u$; substitution is then the process of replacing the variable $u$ with an actual derivation of $A$.

So is it just saying that if we can prove "B true" from assumption "A true", and if we can prove "A true" from some unspecified assumptions (that are the leaves of the proof tree D), then we can in fact prove "B true" from the same unspecified assumptions by combining proof tree D with the proof tree which witnesses that from "A true" we can prove "B true"? I still don't understand why there is a need for a horizontal line (labeled $u$) and would go wrong (if anything) if we didn't have that line.

Mostly an inessential matter of syntax. Different authors might use different conventions.

But in lecture 2 the author seems to be making a big deal of the difference between the presence of a line/bar and its absence (see e.g. his example on implication on page 4). I suppose there must be a reason why the line/bar notation matters in this substitution lemma (?)

Okay, so in lecture 2 they seem to establish that the horizontal bars denote discharged hypotheses, and in lecture 3 they present an undischarged hypothesis with a horizontal bar. That is confusing, and probably an oversight. Then again, it's hard to be precise with natural deduction, because it is by nature an "informal" formalism. Using sequents makes all these notational issues go away. You should probably not focus on this too much.

I shall provide an interim, but I hope, workable enough answer, later to be replaced with a permanent one.
Discharging a hypothesis is essentially to relieve a formula of its function as a hypothesis by making it a constituent (subformula) conclusion of a proof/subproof. Note that a hypothesis never occurring as a constituent of a conclusion would be a spurious one.
Consider the following table from Wikipedia (later I shall replace it with a MathJax one). We see three inference rules (implication introduction, negation introduction, and proof by contradiction) that discharge hypotheses:

The line with the label 'u' on its left (because the proof might employ more than one hypothesis) separates the categorical part from the hypothetical, signalling that the part below the line has a hypothesis is at work; it's the author's choice.
In the text, the judgement 'A true' is the hypothesis and the line as explained. As for the substitution of $\mathcal{D}$, a "hasty" analogy can be drawn for the sake of quick explanation to the following case:
Suppose we have two lines
(1) Assume x is 2
(2) The total is x + 3
(3) 'The total is 5' true
The subproof $\mathcal{D}$ works like the lines (1) and (2), hence we can substitute it anywhere  "'The total is 5' true" occurs.
